# WYSIWYG editor appends 2 forward slash in script tag

Tags: php, magento, wysiwyg, magento2

Currently I am working on magento 2

So my Question is

**Why WYSIWYG editor appends // in script tag? While saving CMS page or CMS block**

`//` are appended after script tag starts and before script tag close

it is continuously appending `//` while save page or block

- Is there any reason of it?
- If want to overcome that than how to do that?

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
// <![CDATA[
// 
// 
// 
   require(['jquery'],function($){
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert("test")       
      });
   });          
// 
// 
// 
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Is that making any problem in in frontend?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. No it is not.. but i only need to know that.. why it is happening.. or any solution of it?